# Blazor why CaptureUnmatchedValues not works as expected?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm building some wrapper around select list.

Let's consider a basic example:

`DictListComponent.razor`:

```
 @using System.Linq.Expressions
 @typeparam T

 <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
    <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="null"> </MudSelectItem>
    <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="1">1</MudSelectItem>
    <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="2">2</MudSelectItem>
</MudSelect>
```

usage would be

```
 <DictMudSelectComponent  @bind-Value="@model.dict1"  For="@(() => @model.dict1)" ></DictMudSelectComponent>
```

This is fine. Then if I want to change to pass this AnchorOrigin from parent like, usage would be:

```
<DictMudSelectComponent  @bind-Value="@model.dict1"  For="@(() => @model.dict1)"  AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter"></DictMudSelectComponent>
```

Then in `DictListComponent.razor` I add

```
 <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" @attributes=AllOtherAttributes>
    <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="null"> </MudSelectItem>
    <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="1">1</MudSelectItem>
    <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="2">2</MudSelectItem>
</MudSelect>

@code
{
 [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
 public Dictionary<string, object> AllOtherAttributes { get; set; } = new(); 
}
```

At runtime I get

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'AnchorOrigin' on object of type 'MudBlazor.MudSelect`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.
> The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'AnchorOrigin' on object of type 'MudBlazor.MudSelect`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.CallPropertySetter[MudSelect`1,Origin](Action`2 setter, Object target, Object value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView.SetParameterProperties(Object target)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
> at MudBlazor.MudBaseInput`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<>n__1(ParameterView parameters) at MudBlazor.MudBaseInput`1.d__177[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()

Why does this not work? What am I missing here?

Thanks and regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `AnchorOrigin="@(Origin.BottomCenter)"`

because I think that without the `@` it is just passed as a string.

Comment: You are right thanks ;) but why in original  <MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="Value" For="@For" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
@ is not reqired ??

Comment: Because MudSelect declares it as an explicit Parameter. CaptureUnmatchedValues does not know about types.